# getting null pointer exception in ios using json in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried below code like this ,

```
NSDictionary * callDict = meetingdictparams;

// convert your dictionary to NSData
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:callDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
// this is your service request url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:meetingupdateurlparams]];
// set the content as format
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
// this is your response type
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
// send the synchronous connection
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
// here add your server response NSJSONSerialization
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
NSLog(@"json array is %@",jsonArray);

// if u want to check the data in console
NSString *tmp=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
```

getting errror like this,

```
             java.lang.NullPointerException
             status code:503
               backenederror
```

I checked that server url in postman..it's working properly....

and I am sending parameters as this..

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary  alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:_MeetingTypeId,@"meetingTyp",Meetingtitletxtfld.text,@"meetinTitle",Meetingdistxtfld.text,@"meetDescription",_Starttimestr,@"startTym",Meetinglengthtxtfld.text,@"hours",Useridstr,@"meetOwnId",_ProjId,@"projectId",[[meetDate componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]objectAtIndex:0],@"meetDate",_MeetingId,@"meetingId",_ConfOwnerId,@"ConferRoomId",nil];

NSLog(@"all key values are %@",dictionary);
```

so,anyone can help in this issuance..thanks in advance....

Comment: You are not getting the null pointer exception on iOS in fact it's allowed to send messages to null objects on Obj-C. Check your problem on the server side.

Comment: but url is working properly in postman..

Comment: I'd make sure my requests are identical with the one I send from postman.

Comment: Is any of you value contains `nil`? Check before create a dictionary. If you find any `nil` value use [`[NSNull null]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622915/3589771).

Comment: nope..am not sending any nil values...i printed that dictionary values before parsing..it...while i checked at server side..it shows error  Format...at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse (SimpleDateFormat.java:1380)

Comment: ".i printed that dictionary values before parsing..it.": No, you need to print `[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to be sure that you send the same data that in POSTMAN.

Comment: when am printing this [NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] getting same error ...domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: is there any solution for this?